# Angular 4 reactive forms custom validator form error c: undefined

Tags: angular

I have a custom validator to evaluate 2 controller values; totalDisch should be more than damaNumb

**Component file:**

```
   form = new FormGroup({
    hospital: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
    department: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    damaDt: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    damaNumb: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    totalDisch: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    notes: new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(125))
}, invalidDama);
```

**The custom validator within the same file**

```
export function invalidDama(c: AbstractControl) {
  //safety check

  if (!c.get('damaNumb').value || !c.get('totalDisch').value) {
    return {c: c.get('totalDisch').setErrors(null)};
  }

  if (c.get('damaNumb').value < c.get('totalDisch').value) {
    return {c: c.get('totalDisch').setErrors(null)};
  }
  return {c: c.get('totalDisch').setErrors({invalidDama: true})};
}
```

**The html template**

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="damaNumb">DAMA Number:</label>
            <input type="number" formControlName="damaNumb" id="damaNumb" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter DAMA Number (1-100)" [(ngModel)]="damaNumb" [min]="1" [max]="100" />
            <div *ngIf="form.get('damaNumb').touched && form.get('damaNumb').invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="form.get('damaNumb').errors.required">DAMA Number is required....</div>
                <div *ngIf="form.get('damaNumb').errors.min">Minimum "1"....</div>
                <div *ngIf="form.get('damaNumb').errors.max">Maximum "100"....</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="totalDisch">Total Discharges:</label>
            <input type="number" formControlName="totalDisch" id="totalDisch" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Total Discharges (1-100)" [(ngModel)]="totalDisch" [min]="1" [max]="100" />
            <div *ngIf="form.get('totalDisch').touched && form.get('totalDisch').invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="form.get('totalDisch').errors.required">Total Discharges is required....</div>
                <div *ngIf="form.get('totalDisch').errors.min">Minimum "1"....</div>
                <div *ngIf="form.get('totalDisch').errors.max">Maximum "100"....</div>
                <div *ngIf="form.get('totalDisch').errors.invalidDama">Discharges can not be less than DAMA....</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The validator works as expected but 
The page submits but in the console form is always invalid and errors

**Console error**

> _errors : c : undefined

Any help?
Thank you in advance............

Comment: Please post properly formatted and indented code, so that we can read it. And if you're asking about an error, post the exact and complete error you get. Also, note that the role of a validator is not to set errors into fields. The role is to return errors. Angular adds the returned error to the form group.

Comment: Sorry for the bad format, i fixed the question to the best of my knowledge..  Actually i dont get an error on submission, the error is in the console and it prevents validating the save button using disabled directive

Comment: I get this error  
Error TS2345 (TS) Argument of type '{ validator: (c: AbstractControl) => { c: void; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn'.

Comment: I indented the function for you. Any decent IDE can do that with a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: *the error is in the console*: so, what is it? Copy and paste it. But again, read the documentation about validators. They are supposed to return sothing like this: `{ errorType: true }`, to indicate that the error of type errorType exists on the form group. They're not supposed to modify the form controls.

Comment: I log the form in the console, so when i check the status it is always INVALID and the errors are only c: undefined...

Comment: Please create a stackblitz that showcases this error :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I don't know to to push the app to stackbitz...

Comment: please see the answer to that post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508416/angular-reactive-populating-the-select-control-of-the-edit-form-fails/47736161#47736161][1]

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the custom validator in the respective Form element.

```
 totalDisch: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,invalidDama(input val or regex)]),
```

Comment: if you want to read any params from input field you can do it by adding `invalidDama(val)` and in html `invalidDama="xyz"` Eg: minLength="10". 
If you don't want any params then simply use
`totalDisch: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,invalidDama])`

Comment: I did ('',[Validators.required,invalidDama])   but i got this error Cannot read property 'value' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at invalidDama (dama-form.component.ts?2b95:160)  line 160 is  if (!c.get('damaNumb').value || !c.get('totalDisch').value) {

Comment: just use `!c.value` instead of `!c.get('damaNumb').value`

Comment: Thanks for your respectful help..  I did (if (!c.value || !c.value), now i have this error    Cannot read property 'setErrors' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setErrors' of null
    at invalidDama (dama-form.component.ts?2b95:161)  line 161 is  return { c: c.get('totalDisch').setErrors(null) };

Comment: `c.setErrors({invalidDama: true})`

Comment: what about that error    Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Comment: can you share your complete error that you are getting

Comment: the error in the console    RROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
    at FormControl.AbstractControl._updateControlsErrors (vendor.js?v=2zcansG3lYw2B--DultdGg7QLm-UWt8_wc5qHH0y838:88318)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl.setErrors (vendor.js?v=2zcansG3lYw2B--DultdGg7QLm-UWt8_wc5qHH0y838:88254)
    at invalidDama (dama-form.component.ts?2b95:161)
    at vendor.js?v=2zcan

Answer (score 0):

Your validator should look like this:

```
const ageValidator: ValidatorFn = (fg: FormGroup) => {
  const damaNumb = fg.get('damaNumb').value;
  const totalDisch = fg.get('totalDisch').value;

  if (totalDisch > damaNumb ) {
    return null;
  }
  fg.get('totalDisch').markAsTouched();
  fg.get('totalDisch').setErrors({ invalidDama: true });
  return { invalidDama: true };
};
```

Since it's a fg-level validator, the return will be a fg-level error. If you want additional errors on specific controls, you have to set them with setErrors like in this example.