# Angular reactive: Populating the select control of the edit form fails

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to Angular and I have an edit form using Angular 4 reactive forms, trying to populate the select with department, the rule is the hospital is populated from the user.hospital, then a cascading dropdown department based on the hospital
while the hospital is correctly displayed, the department fails..
in the console, the populated department is showing the departmentId correctly.

edit component:

```
    form = new FormGroup({
        hospital: new FormControl({ value: 'hospitalId', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
        department: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
);
    damaId: number;
    me: any;

    hospitals: any[];
    selectedHospital: any;
    departments: any[];
    availableDepartments: any[];
    selectedDepartment: any;
    user: string = '';



    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private commonService: CommonService,
        private damaService: DamaService,
        private accountEndpoint: AccountEndpoint,
        private toastyService: ToastyService) {

        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(
            params => {
                let id = +params['id'];
                this.getDama(id);
            }
        );

        this.accountEndpoint.getUserEndpoint()
            .subscribe(response => {
                const me = response.json();
                this.dama.userId = me.id;
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        const sources = [
            this.accountEndpoint.getUserEndpoint(),
            this.commonService.getHospitals(),
            this.commonService.getDepartments(),
            this.commonService.getApproves(),
        ];
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(
            params => {
                let id = +params['id'];
                this.getDama(id);
            }
        );
        Observable.forkJoin(sources).subscribe(
            data => {
                const me = data[0].json();
                this.me = me;
                this.dama.userId = me.id;

                this.hospitals = data[1];
                this.departments = data[2];
                this.approves = data[3];

                this.initializeSelectedHospital();
                this.filterDepartments();
            },
            err => {
                if (err.status == 404)
                    this.router.navigate(['/damas']);
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    getDama(id: number): void {
        this.damaService.getDama(id)
            .subscribe(
            (dama: SaveDama) => this.onDamaRetrieved(dama),
            (error: any) => {
                if (error.status == 404)
                    this.router.navigate(['/damas'])
            });
    }

    onDamaRetrieved(dama: SaveDama): void {

        //Update the data on the form
        this.form.patchValue({
            hospital: this.dama.hospitalId,
            department: this.dama.departmentId,

        })
    }
    private initializeSelectedHospital() {
        this.selectedHospital = this.hospitals.find(h => h.id === this.me.hospitalId);
    }

    private filterDepartments() {
        this.availableDepartments = this.selectedHospital.departments;
    }


    public submit() {
        console.log(this.form);
        if (this.form.dirty) {
            //copy the form values over the dama object values
            let p = Object.assign({}, this.dama, this.form.value);
            this.damaService.update(p)
                .subscribe(x => {
                    x.toastyService.success({
                        title: 'Success',
                        msg: 'Form was sucessfully Updated.',
                        theme: 'bootstrap',
                        showClose: true,
                        timeout: 5000
```

the Html page:

```
                <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="hospital" hospital=""></label>
                    <select id="hospital" class="form-control" formControlName="hospital" [(ngModel)]="selectedHospital">
                        <option value="undefined">Select a hospital</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let h of hospitals" [ngValue]="h">{{ h.name }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="department">Department:</label>
                    <select id="department" class="form-control" formControlName="department" [disabled]="!availableDepartments" [(ngModel)]="selectedDepartment">
                        <option value="undefined" disabled>
                            Select a department
                            <span *ngIf="selectedHospital">from "{{selectedHospital?.name}}"</span>
                        </option>
                        <option *ngFor="let d of availableDepartments" [ngValue]="d">{{d.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <div *ngIf="form.get('department').touched && form.get('department').invalid" class="alert alert-danger">Department is required....</div>
                </div>
```

the SaveDama model

```
 export class SaveDama {
    id: number;
    departmentId: number;
    hospitalId: number;
    damaNumb: number;
    totalDisch: number;
    damaDt: string;
    dataEntryTime: string;
    latestUpdate: string;
    on: string;
    approvedOn: string;
    approveId: number;
    notes: string;
    userId: string;

}
```

I appreciate you help.....

Comment: why are you using `formControlName` with `ngModel` in your `<select>` ?

Comment: I need to get the value of the hospital to update the department

Comment: You have way to much code in your question. Create the minimal code to be able to reproduce this issue. And Mohamed is right, do not mix ngModel with reactive form. This results in two bindings and can cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

The function is simplified with following code:

```
    function invalidDama(input: FormControl) {

   if (!input.value) {
       return null;
   }

   const goodNumb = input.value.damaNumb < input.value;
   return goodNumb ? null : { badNumb: true };
}
```

and the validation div

```
 <div *ngIf="form.get('totalDisch').errors.invalidDama">Discharges can not be less than DAMA....</div>
```